# Frame-independent movement issue in PyGame with Rect class

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a simple game with PyGame, and I've run into a problem getting things moving properly. I'm not experienced with game programming, so I'm not sure if my approach is even correct..

I have a class Ball, which extends PyGame's Sprite class. Each frame, the Ball object is supposed to move around the screen. I'm using frame-independent(?)/time-based movement with the time delta returned by PyGame's Clock object each time around. Such as,

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   # . . .
   def update(self, delta):
       self.rect.x += delta * self.speed  # speed is pixels per second
       self.rect.y += delta * self.speed  # ... or supposed to be, anyway
```

... and ...

```
class Game(object):
    # . . .
    def play(self):
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        while not self.done:
            delta = self.clock.tick(self.fps) / 1000.0  # time is seconds
            self.ball.update(delta)
```

PyGame's Sprite class is backed by a Rect object (rect) that tracks the sprite's position. And Rect's coordinates are automatically converted to integers whenever a value is updated. So, my problem is that each time update() is called, any extra fraction-of-a-pixel movement is lost, instead of being accumulated over time as it should. Speed in "pixels per second" isn't accurate this way. Even worse, if the amount of movement per frame is less than one pixel, the ball doesn't move at all for those frames, because it's always rounded down to zero. (i.e., no movement if pps < fps)

I'm not sure how to deal with this. I tried adding separate x and y values to Ball which aren't forced to be integers and updating the rect every time those change. That way the x and y values accumulate the fractions of a pixel as normal. As in,

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #  . . .
    def update(self, delta):
        self.x += delta * self.speed
        self.y += delta * self.speed
    def getx(self):
        return self._x
    def setx(self, val):
        self._x = val      # this can be a float
        self.rect.x = val  # this is converted to int
    def gety(self):
        return self._y
    def sety(self, val):
        self._y = val      # this can be a float
        self.rect.y = val  # this is converted to int
    x = property(getx,setx)
    y = property(gety,sety)
```

But that ends up being messy: it's easy to update the rect object when x and y change, but not the other way around. Not to mention the Rect object has lots of other useful coordinates that can be manipulated (like centerx, top, bottomleft, etc. -- which is why one would still want to move the rect directly). I'd more or less end up having to re-implement the whole Rect class in Ball, to store floats before it passes them down to the rect object, or else do everything based on just x and y, sacrificing some of the convenience of the Rect class either way.

Is there a smarter way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but I figured this out a bit ago and thought I'd give this question an answer since I came across it in trying to figure out what was going on. (Thanks for helping me confirm the issue, by the way.)

You can make use of Python's `round` function. Pretty much, just throw what you want into that function, and it'll spit out a properly rounded number.

The first way I got it working was like this:

```
x = box['rect'].x
if leftDown:
   x -= 300 * deltaTime
if rightDown:
   x += 300 * deltaTime

box['rect'].x = round(x)
```

(Where my deltaTime is a float, being a fraction of a second.)

As long as you're putting the float value you get through the `round` function before applying it, that should do the trick. It doesn't have to use separate variables or anything.

It may be worth noting that you cannot draw in fractions of a pixel. Ever. If you're familiar with a Lite-Brite, pixels work in that way, being a single lit up light. That's why the number you use in the end has to be an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure your solution accomplishes anything. It looks like you're trying to use that extra `x` variable to keep track of the tiny little pixel fractions, but the first line overwrites them with the integer value stored in the Rect object's `x` value. It's slightly different from the default behavior, because you explicitly use the `round()` function, instead of casting to an `int` (what Rect apparently does by default).

Anyway, for my problem it turned out this wasn't as big an issue I thought it was. I cleaned up my code elsewhere and the movement issues sorted themselves out.

Comment: The Rect was stored in the dictionary there. `x` takes a copy of the x position for that Rect. Keys adjust that position, where my deltaTime is a float. So the `x` ends up as a float. At the end, the float is rounded correctly, with the Rect truncating off what is just a 0, from what I understand. It worked for me and my simple moving box at least. I could also just do something like `box['rect'] += round(300 * deltaTime)`. I think the whole thing really comes down to handling rounding yourself. Glad you figured out your particular situation. :)